# xargs with variable number of arguments

Tags: shell, xargs

I am trying to create a command to show logs for all running allocations in a [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/) cluster. I can get the allocation IDs with this command:

```
curl -s $NOMAD_ADDR/v1/allocations | jq -r '.[] | select(.JobID=="MY_JOB_NAME") | "\(.ID)"'
```

From there I would like to run [multitail](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) with `nomad logs <allocation> -tail -f` for each allocation so that I can watch all of the logs at once. The syntax of a multitail call looks like this:

```
multitail [options] -l "shell 1 command" -l "shell 2 command" -l...
```

If you open 5 shells, then you need 5 `-l` arguments.

I do not see this functionality in the `xargs` manual, but I need something like `xargs multitail --arg-for-each "-l my shell command {}"`. Is it possible to use xargs to construct commands with variable numbers of arguments in this way? If not, is there any alternative that I can use to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is a list of ids.  For the purposes of this answer, let's say that looks like:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

You want to transform this into:

```
multitail \
    -l "nomad logs foo -tail -f" \
    -l "nomad logs bar -tail -f" \
    -l "nomad logs baz -tail -f"
```

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
eval multitail $(command_that_generates_ids | xargs -IID echo "-l 'nomad logs ID -tail -f'")
```

Comment:  Works like a charm! Thanks. What does the automatic newline escaping?

Comment: Uh...what automatic newline escaping?

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but it seems like since echo prints a newline at the end, the resulting multi-line string could be interpreted as separate commands.

Comment: It will just be interpreted as whitespace and needs no special handling.

Comment: If you _wanted_ the \n to be interpreted as \n, you would do: "$(...)"